# Silverlight 4 DomainService - EntitiesInError - EntityConflict - PropertyNames throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria, domainservices

Following an [introductory tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20151210133942/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/16/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-updating-data-in-the-client.aspx) for the new DomainService in Silverlight 4 RIA, I got an unexpected exception. When I perform an update the property `EntitiesInError[index].EntityConflict.PropertyNames` throws the following exception:

**InvalidOperationException: PropertyNames are not available for delete conflicts.**

Service method executed:

```
public void UpdateSr_Supplier(sr_Supplier currentsr_Supplier)
{
    // UPDATE the existing sr_Supplier
    this.ObjectContext.sr_Supplier.AttachAsModified(currentsr_Supplier, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentsr_Supplier));
}
```

From the answer on [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20110110235957/http://forums.silverlight.net:80/forums/p/92540/214580.aspx) I gather that I should rather use Silverlight-enabled services with custom service objects (`DataContract` and `DataMember`), then assign the values of these custom service objects to the actual server objects (generated from the DB model, be that Linq to Sql or the Entity Data Model), and manually call `SubmitChanges()` on the DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PropertyNames will throw an exception if the error you're dealing with is a deletion conflict, this is normal. You should be looking for the underlying database error, which may be neglecting to set a non-null value or a primary key violation, etc.

Comment: It worked once I changed the setter of my identity to public. I guess I should use the metadata for custom read-only rules rather than the entity designer.